# Difference between UI GRID and NG GRID

Tags: user-interface, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

my project requirement is that we only use ui-grid. I understand that ui grid is a just a new version(ng-grid is older and ui-grid is newer).

But for pagination , i have written directive that uses  ng-class and ng-click.. are this part of ui-grid or ng-grid..with these directives am I still using ui-grid?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are. ng-class and ng-click are just standard Angular event handlers, not specific to ng-grid.